# When I performed Google login, it returns error " Invalid Granted" with frappe

Tags: cordova, frappe

Firstly, I have setup Google Login Frappe ERPNext. it returns success.

Now, when I am using Frappe API for Google Login, api/method/frappe.www.login.login_via_google, using below parameters and it returns error " Invalid Grant"

state:eyJzaXRlIjogImh0dHBzOi8veW9zd2l0LnR1aXRtZW50LmNvbSIsICJ0b2tlbiI6ICJjNGYzZTc4ODI4YzFlMDM3YmViOTI1NTliZmUxZDNkMDJhZTNiYzcxOWM0OGFjMWFhNGUwNTU4ZCIsICJyZWRpcmVjdF90byI6IG51bGx9

- code: 4/0AVHEtk4HKVIrvpGPwni6EbgGED_t4ZBHkIJHeUO0f6xeGmZN5U2C36c2IUeYbImMrodiug
- scope: email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid