# When I performed Facebook Login, it returns error "Invalid verification code format" with frappe

Tags: cordova, frappe

Firstly, I have setup Facebook Login in Frappe ERPNext. it returns success.

Now, when I am using Frappe API for Facebook Login, api/method/frappe.www.login.login_via_facebook it returns error as below

“'Decoder failed to handle access_token with data as returned by provider. A different decoder may be needed. Provider returned: b'{"error":{"message":"Invalid verification code format.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AydlqbkcvgmK5r0d6UCHlue"}}''
”

Parameters passed as below

- code: i have pass Facebook login after get access token parameter value here
- state: eyJzaXRlIjogImh0dHBzOi8veW9zd2l0LnR1aXRtZW50LmNvbSIsICJ0b2tlbiI6ICI4N2ExMGIzNjYzNDk1NDA1MjRkNmZjOGQ4MzBlZDY0ODdkNDhiZjY4N2U1MTJiN2VlYjQ0M2M2NyIsICJyZWRpcmVjdF90byI6IG51bGx9

If any one has idea regarding above problem then please guide me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I performed Google login, it returns error " Invalid Granted" with frappe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75995836/when-i-performed-google-login-it-returns-error-invalid-granted-with-frappe)